# rails application in beta mode on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a best practice for beta moding with rails. What I mean by that is to be able to turn beta mode in application and enable some content that would otherwise not be enabled.

Is there something built in inside rails for this?

Comment: You may want to have a look at the [flip gem](https://github.com/pda/flip) or something similar.